# How do I (efficiently) compare the n-th line in file A with the n-th line in file B?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have two files, `a.txt` and `b.txt`. Both files contain numbers only, one number per line. Here is the beginning of `a.txt`:

```
2
5
154
1749
...
```

`b.txt` is similar, but it has different numbers. I want to compare the number on the $n^{\rm th}$ row in `a.txt` with the number on the same row of `b.txt`, and depending on the result, do some processing. Example:

```
If[nth_number_a > nth_number_b, doSomething(), doSomethingElse()]
```

Both files are fairly large, of the order of 200 MB, and I need to compare all of the numbers inside the files, linewise.

How can I efficiently perform this kind of comparison? How can I compare all $n^{\rm th}$ rows in both files in Mathematica? For info, I am using version 11.1.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/166353/whats-the-fastest-way-to-read-a-simple-numerical-list

Comment: What if files have different number of lines? What if some of the lines can't be interpreted as numbers? Are these files always expected to be small enough for their contents could be assumed to fit to kernel memory at the same time? All of these questions affect the preferred method to choose.

Comment: I created a 220 MB file with RandomInteger, then Imported it in MMA's memory. The import took 17 seconds and the further operations were very fast. The naive approach to import them in memory and compare them there seems perfectly viable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to read both lists to memory first, then use normal list/part operations in Mathematica. i.e the nth row is just `a[[n]]` after reading the file and same for `b[[n]]`. I do not think there will be problem  with reading 200 MB plain text file using Mathematica.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]

aNumbers = Import["A.txt", "List"]
bNumbers = Import["B.txt", "List"]

Do[(*assume same Length, change as needed if not*)
 If[aNumbers[[n]] == bNumbers[[n]],
  Print["number A[",n,"]=", aNumbers[[n]]," is same as number B[", n, "]"],
  Print["number A[",n,"]=", aNumbers[[n]]," is not same as number B[",n,"]=",bNumbers[[n]]]
  ]
 ,
 {n, Length@aNumbers}
 ]
```

For example given these two files

[image]

You will get this output

[image]

So after importing, these will be just normal lists:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and now you can do with these lists anything you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use streams instead of importing full files:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]] ;

a = Range[100] ;
b = Range[100] ;

Export["a.txt", a, "Table"] ;
Export["b.txt", b, "Table"] ;

ClearAll[read] ;
read[file_, line_] := With[
    {stream = OpenRead[file]}, 
    Do[ReadLine[stream], line - 1] ; 
    ReadLine[stream]
] ;
```

Read for given line:

```
read["a.txt", 50]
read["b.txt", 50]
(* 50 *)
(* 50 *)
```

Returns `EndOfFile` if requested line is larger than total number of lines:

```
read["a.txt", 1001]
(* EndOfFile *)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's interesting. But if I want to go through a file with 10k lines for example, it will make 10k calls to `OpenRead` ? That is very inefficient. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: yes, 10k calls it is, upto o(n) time and constant space

Comment: But not 10k calls to `OpenRead`? One call to that function, then 10k calls to `ReadLine`.  Or is my mental interpretation of the code incorrect.

Comment: right, you point at file with open, than single read returns a line and points to the next

Comment: also, if you on linux, you can use `sed -n <line>p <file>` with `RunProcess`

Answer (score 3):

If your files indeed have identical number of lines and they're small enough to fit on computer memory at the same time, the fastest and most straight-forward way to process them is probably just this (with random example data):

```
MapThread[If[#1 >= #2, "First larger or equal", "Last larger"] &, 
 Import[#, "List"] & /@ {"a.txt", "b.txt"}]

(* {"First larger or equal", "Last larger", "Last larger",
    "Last larger", "Last larger", "Last larger", "Last larger",
    "First larger or equal", "First larger or equal",
    "First larger or equal"} *)
```

Now you can just index this array to get the answer for $n$th line.

If you want to process line numbers too in your comparison function (not really done below, but anyway), you can do something like this:

```
MapIndexed[{First@#2, 
   If[#1[[1]] >= #1[[2]], "First larger or equal", "Last larger"]} &, 
 Transpose[Import[#, "List"] & /@ {"a.txt", "b.txt"}]]

(*  {{1, "First larger or equal"}, {2, "First larger or equal"}, {3, 
      "Last larger"}, {4, "First larger or equal"}, {5, 
      "Last larger"}, {6, "First larger or equal"}, {7, 
      "Last larger"}, {8, "First larger or equal"}, {9, 
      "First larger or equal"}, {10, "First larger or equal"}} *)
```

If your files have a differing number of lines, you can use `PadRight` to pacify `MapThread` or `Transpose`.

If they're too large to fit in the memory comfortably, the best solution probably involves `ReadLine`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functionn that does not read the whole file into memory. It only reads line after line. This may be handy for large files.

```
getLine[n_, filename_] := Module[{fil, s},
  fil = OpenRead[filename];
  If[n == 2, ReadLine[fil],
   Do[Find[fil, "\n"];, n - 2]
   ];
  s = Read[fil, Record, NullRecords -> True];
  Close[fil];
  s]
```