# Report sum of each list seperately

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm looking to calculate the variance of the total of multiple lists. To do this accurately I will need each list sum to be reported separately, and recorded in a list, to then perform the variance calculations. An example of what I mean is shown below:

```
MyData  = {{2,10,9,8,4,1},{2,3,4},{0,1,10,20}...{4,2}}
```

To get:

```
MySum = {{34},{9},{31}...{6}}
MySD = StandardDeviation[MySum]
```

I could import each list individually, and then total manually etc. However, there are 1000s of lists and they are very large. If someone could show me an elegant way of doing this, it would be hugely appreciated.

How I import my datasets is below, for context:
Al2O3;

```
SetDirectory["MyFilePath"];

MyFileNames = FileNames["*.fileextension"];

MyDataLists = Import[#, {"Data", All, 6}] & /@ MyFileNames;

MyDataLists = {{2,10,9,8,4,1},{2,3,4},{0,1,10,20}...{4,2}}
```

Comment: How about: `Total /@ MyData // StandardDeviation` ?

Comment: *See above.* myData = {{2, 10, 9, 8, 4, 1}, {2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 10, 20}, {4, 2}}, mySum = Map[Total, myData], mySD = StandardDeviation[mySum], N[mySD] is a close equivalent to *Syed's*. By the way, as a matter of Mathematica style, it is recommended that users' symbol names **not start** with a capital letter. Wolfram Mathematica uses names starting with capital letters. You do not to collide with Mathematica's symbols.

Comment: Also `mySum=Total[MyData,{2}]`

Comment: Possibly related to your problem of reading a list of numbers https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166548/60568